# Query to show all ID's except the ones that have a specific instrument

Tags: sql

So I have a table which looks like this:

[image]

What would be the best query to exclude every "stuknr" that has atleast 1 "saxofoon" in the "instrumentnaam" column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select all `stuknr` where there is not stuknr with a saxofoon:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE stuknr not in (
   SELECT stuknr 
   FROM TABLE 
   WHERE INSTRUMENTNAAM = ‘saxofoon’)
;
```

Comment: But, remeber, saxophone is not bad, listen to: [Top 20 saxophone songs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tL6oQ3pD8rI)  

Comment: I'm more of a bass guitar person :), but it's for a homework assignment so it might be my professors opinion

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STUNKR 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE INSTRUMENTNAAM != ‘saxofoon’;
```

Here `!=`  (or `<>`, which are equivalent, see [this](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/07/08/sql-difference-between-and-operator-used-for-not-equal-to-operation/)) means "not equal".

Comment: This only excludes the rows that have 'saxofoon' in them. For example "stuknr" 2 has 4 rows, and i want to exclude them all because atleast 1 of those rows has 'saxofoon'

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a NOT IN sub-select

```
select distinct 
      YT.stunkr
   from
      YourTable YT
         where YT.stunkr NOT IN ( select distinct stunkr
                                     from YourTable
                                     where InstrumentNaam = 'saxofoon' )
```

So the sub-select is getting all IDs that DO have saxofoon and the primary select/from is getting where the ID is NOT in the secondary.